# single line break In while loop

Tags: php, html, loops, while-loop

I would like to have a single `<br>` in my while loop.
If I add the `<br>` I get a `<br>` for single item, what I want is that only `<br>` is shown between `<img>` and `<button>`. So not for every button separately. Can someone help me?

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
?>

<img src="<?php echo $result_question['img'];?>">

<input type="button" id="<?php echo $row["answer_id"];?>" next_question_id="<?php echo $row["next_question_id"];?>" value="<?php echo $row["answer_text"];?>" onclick=myFunction2((this.id));>

<?php   
    }
} 
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Sorry. I fail to understand your requirement. Can you please elaborate so that I can help if possible ?

Comment: check `$row["answer_text"]` OR `$row["answer_id"]`  in if condition with your desired text OR id before printing <br>;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you mean?

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $c = 0;
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
?>

<img src="<?php echo $result_question['img'];?>">
<?php if ($c == 0){ ?><br/><?php } ?> 

<input type="button" id="<?php echo $row["answer_id"];?>" next_question_id="<?php echo $row["next_question_id"];?>" value="<?php echo $row["answer_text"];?>" onclick=myFunction2((this.id));>

<?php  
    $c++; 
    }
} 
$conn->close();
?>
```